# Multiple parameter in JPA query and method

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-native-query

I want to pass multiple parameters around(20) in my JPA method. So is there any way in which I can pass an Object as a parameter in my JPA method?
How can I use @Param annotation which can take values from my object and assign it to my native query attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get close by using Spel Expressions.

```
@Query("select u from User u where u.firstname = :#{#customer.firstname}")
List<User> findUsersByCustomersFirstname(@Param("customer") Customer customer);
```

You can pass an object(like Customer) to your query methods and then use its reference to set your query params.

Check out the official [docs](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions) for more details

Comment: I don't have much reputation for that.